# How should I test a role in molecule with various calling methods?

Tags: ansible, molecule

Assuming the I have the `foo` role which I am testing via the `foo` molecule scenario on several platforms.

My playbook.yml current looks like:

```
- import_role:
    name: foo
```

Now I do want to check if calling the same role with some optional variable also works and the code would look like:

```
- import_role:
    name: foo
  vars:
    foo_use_upstream: true
```

Obviously that I cannot reliably run it after the first one because the system would be in an already altered state.

Sadly I do no thave a remove-foo role that I can use and lets assume that it would be too much efforth to attempt to implement one.

I know that I could create additional scenario like `foo-with-upstream`.

Still multiple scenario approach does not scale well at all as it would easily become a maintenance nightmare on projects hosting more than >10 roles.

Is there another way I can use molecule to cover for this case? ... once that could start from clean docker containers on the additional use-cases?

Comment: As you mention, this is best solved with scenarios. I am not sure how it would be a "maintenance nightmare" as this is how acceptance testing on this kind of thing is solved by all relevant software in general.

Comment: Maybe `--base-config` option to help?